# T-SQL wildcard search all values in comma delimited variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to get matching record with all values in the variables.
e.g., 001, 3

Should return record that has 001 and 3 in their `UnitId`.

What is wrong with my statement? It only returns the matching record for the first item in comma delimited variable.

```
DECLARE @SearchTags AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '001, 3';

SELECT 
    Asset.UnitId, Asset.Description
FROM 
    Asset
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT Split.XMLString.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            FROM 
                (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@SearchTags, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS [XML]) AS XMLString
            CROSS APPLY 
                [XML].nodes('/X') AS Split(XMLString)
            WHERE 
                Asset.UnitId LIKE '%' + Split.XMLString.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') + '%'
           )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef0fc4/1)

Comment: `001, 3` is split into `001` and `_3`. Note there is a space before the `3`. You need to trim it off before doing the comparison

Comment: @Squirrel yeah found it. extra space after the comma. Thank you

Comment: ...are you _really_ still running SQL Server 2012? Why are you running [an unsupported DB today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-2012)? - if you update to SQL Server 2016 or later then you can split strings more efficiently in a single-line with [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Comment: Also... why is your database denormalized like that? Can't you move the embedded CSV data over to a proper table?